# Convert four bytes to Integer using C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert 4 bytes to an integer using C++.

This is my code:

```
int buffToInteger(char * buffer)
{
    int a = (int)(buffer[0] << 24 | buffer[1] << 16 | buffer[2] << 8 | buffer[3]);
    return a;
}
```

The code above works in almost all cases, for example:
When my buffer is: `"[\x00, \x00, \x40, \x00]"` the code will return `16384` as expected.

But when the buffer is filled with: `"[\x00, \x00, \x3e, \xe3]"`, the code won't work as expected and will return `"ffffffe1"`.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: ".. the code won't work as expected": Your code *does* work as expected (because I expect this behavior with signed byte values).

Comment: @Jongware Why it returns ffffffe1 and not 16102? Can you please explain?

Comment: @i486 the problem not in endians.

Comment: @TonyD: that's not right. (But you're looking in the right neighborhood.)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your `buffer` contains *signed* characters. So, actually, `buffer[0] == -29`, which upon conversion to `int` gets sign-extended to `0xffffffe3`, and in turn `(0x3e << 8) | 0xffffffe3 == 0xffffffe3`.

You need ensure your individual `buffer` bytes are interpreted `unsigned`, either by declaring `buffer` as `unsigned char *`, or by explicitly casting:

```
int a = int((unsigned char)(buffer[0]) << 24 |
            (unsigned char)(buffer[1]) << 16 |
            (unsigned char)(buffer[2]) << 8 |
            (unsigned char)(buffer[3]));
```

Comment: Isn't this undefined behavior? As far as I understand, the result type of `(unsigned char)(buffer[0]) << 24` is `int`, and with some values of `buffer[0]`, the operation can overflow the range of 32-bit `int`.

Comment: @khuttun there is a special case just for that: if the type is signed and the left operand is positive, and the result can be represented by the *unsigned* version of the type, then the behavior is defined. The final result will be the conversion to a signed number of the result.

Comment: Thanks @spectras, you are correct: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_shift_operators

Comment: This is a C++ question, but it doesn't look like that special case exists in C. From the latest C23 draft: "6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators [...] The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. [...] The result of E1 << E2 is [...]. If E1 has an unsigned type, [...]. If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 *is representable in the result type*, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." So `((uint8_t)0xFF) << 24` is UB in C assuming a 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 5):

In the expression `buffer[0] << 24` the value 24 is an `int`, so `buffer[0]` will also be converted to an `int` before the shift is performed.

On your system a `char` is apparently signed, and will then be sign extended when converted to `int`.

Answer (score 4):

I think this could be also done with use of `memcpy`:

```
int buffToInteger(char* buffer)
{
    int a;
    memcpy( &a, buffer, sizeof( int ) );
    return a;
}
```

This is much faster than the example mentioned in the original post, because it just treats all bytes "as is" and there is no need to do any operations such as bit shift etc.
It also doesn't cause any signed-unsigned issues.

Comment: This could cause endianness issues, as the bytes could be in little-endian order and the integer in big endian order.

Answer (score 3):

There's a implict promotion to a signed int in your shifts.
That's because char is (apparently) signed on your platform (the common thing) and << promotes to integers implicitly. In fact none of this would work otherwise because << 8 (and higher) would scrub all your bits!

If you're stuck with using a buffer of signed chars this will give you what you want:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int buffToInteger(char * buffer)
{
    int a = static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[0]) << 24 |
        static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[1]) << 16 | 
        static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[2]) << 8 | 
        static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[3]));
    return a;
}

int main(void) {
    char buff[4]={0x0,0x0,0x3e,static_cast<char>(0xe3)};
    int a=buffToInteger(buff);

    std::cout<<std::hex<<a<<std::endl;

    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Be careful about bit shifting on signed values. Promotions don't just add bytes but may convert values.

For example a gotcha here is that you can't use `static_cast<unsigned int>(buffer[1])` (etc.) directly because that converts the signed char value to a signed int and then reinterprets that value as an unsigned.

If anyone asks me all implicit numeric conversions are bad. No program should have so many that they would become a chore. It's a softness in the C++ inherited from C that causes all sorts of problems that far exceed their value.
It's even worse in C++ because they make the already confusing overloading rules even more confusing.

Comment: Does it also work on converting 4bytes to unsigned integer ? or it needs modification ?

Comment: @atari83 Apart from the obvious changes to the return value and inside the function it should be fine. It only really depends on the characters representing a little-endian array containing an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 2):

```
char buffer[4];
int a;
a = *(int*)&buffer;
```

This takes a buffer reference, type casts it to an int reference and then dereferences it.

Comment: Hi Mylotyrena, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain why your code solves the problem.

Comment: This is probably undefined behavior since the buffer may not be aligned to `int`'s 4-byte alignment.

Answer (score 1):

```
int buffToInteger(char * buffer)
{
  return *reinterpret_cast<int*>(buffer);
}
```

This conversion is simple and fast. We only tell compiler to treat a byte array in a memory as a single integer

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.